# How to resolve dpkg errors after upgrading from 18.10 to 19.04?

Tags: upgrade, dpkg

After upgrading from 18.10 to 19.04 I started getting below error during every product installation:

```
dpkg: error processing package sendmail-bin (--configure):
 installed sendmail-bin package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sendmail:
 sendmail depends on sendmail-bin; however:
  Package sendmail-bin is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package sendmail (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of sensible-mda:
 sensible-mda depends on sendmail-bin | mail-transport-agent; however:
  Package sendmail-bin is not configured yet.
  Package mail-transport-agent is not installed.
  Package sendmail-bin which provides mail-transport-agent is not configured yet.
  Package postfix which provides mail-transport-agent is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package sensible-mda (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                                    Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.5-2) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.29-0ubuntu2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sendmail-bin
 sendmail
 sensible-mda
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: are your sources still configured to use bionic instead of disco? go check Software & Updates first, second tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands below

```
$ apt-get install sendmail

$ apt-get -f install

$ apt-get install sendmail
```